# Unit Testing a function which uses a self variables

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have started writing unit tests and right now am in a situation where I need to test a function which uses a self or global class variable.

```
main_class_obj = Mainclass()

@patch.object(main_class_obj, 'db_obj', mock_db_conn)
    def test_transform_coordinates(self):

        expected_result_X = 5462
        expected_result_Y = 9842

        x,y= main_class_obj.transform_links(75,50)
        assert expected_result_X == x
        assert expected_result_Y == y

def transform_links(self, x_coord, y_coord):
    
    try:
        p = pyproj.Proj(self.proj4text)
        x, y= p(x_coord, y_coord, inverse=True)
        return x, y
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Error")
```

In my transform_links function , I am using a self variable, When I run my unit tests its failing to pick it up since its initialized in the init part of the main class.

How does one write unit tests in such scenario.

Comment: The question is, why didn't the `proj4text` attribute get initialized when you called `Mainclass`?

Comment: @chepner I was hoping the same but apparently it didnt

Comment: There's not much we can do without seeing how `Mainclass` is defined.

Comment: Is `transform_links` actually defined as a method of `Mainclass`, or did you just define a regular function?

Comment: @chepner its a member function of the main class

Comment: Could you add the code of `Mainclass` to the question please? Otherwise it's hardly possible to identify the problem.